# MySQL query with Doctrine 2 and different results

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

So here's the thing.

I'm querying the database using Doctrine 2.5 and I'd like to use Doctrine's createQuery() method to do it. The reason is that Doctrine 2 hydrates the results in a camelCase manner, and my column names are all with underscores. And since most of the simple queries work fine with createQuery (or even with the query builder) I'd like to move all native MySQL queries to Doctrine's DQL (to get all results in camelCase so that's a standarized results). Either that or you guys can teach me how to make Doctrine 2 return the results in the same way that the columns are in the database... xD

I have the following query:

```
$sql = '
     SELECT sp.*, so.user_id
     FROM shop_order so
     INNER JOIN shop_payment sp ON(so.payment_id=sp.id)
     WHERE so.id = '.$orderID;
$stmt = $em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch();
```

This results in the following result:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 14
    [payment_type_id] => 2
    [flag] => boleto_bb
    [tid] => 
    [billet] => 1
    [parcel_quantity] => 
    [cart_name_holder] => 
    [cart_date_holder] => 1999-12-01
    [cart_number_holder] => 0
    [datecreated] => 2017-08-30 14:51:25
    [dateupdate] => 2017-08-30 16:36:18
    [status] => 2
    [user_id] => 16
)
```

But if I do it like this:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('
    SELECT sp, so.userId
    FROM ShopOrder so
    INNER JOIN ShopPayment sp WITH (so.paymentId = sp.id)
    WHERE so.id = ' . $orderID);
$result = $query->getArrayResult();
```

I get the following result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 14
                    [paymentTypeId] => 2
                    [flag] => boleto_bb
                    [tid] => 
                    [billet] => 1
                    [parcelQuantity] => 
                    [cartNameHolder] => 
                    [cartDateHolder] => DateTime Object
                        (
                            [date] => 1999-12-01 00:00:00.000000
                        )
                    [cartNumberHolder] => 0
                    [datecreated] => DateTime Object
                        (
                            [date] => 2017-08-30 14:51:25.000000
                        )
                    [dateupdate] => DateTime Object
                        (
                            [date] => 2017-08-30 16:36:18.000000
                        )
                    [status] => 2
                )
            [userId] => 16
        )
)
```

How can I get the first result from the createQuery method?

Comment: You know the queries are vulnerable to SQL injection right now?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?